# s:WindowedApplication is empty and does not initialize/show child components

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have quite some experience with Flex and I am just starting to write my first AIR application and would like to use as much Spark as possible here.

So I started withe a simple Hello World application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" backgroundColor="red"
                       initialize="initializeHandler(event)">

  <s:Label text="Hello World"/>

  <s:Button label="Test" initialize="onButtonInitialize()"/>

  <fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    private function onButtonInitialize():void
    {
      trace("Button");
    }


    private function initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
      trace("Application");
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Unfortunately this simple example shows no child components and even none of the initialize handlers is triggered. However as soon as I change the root tag to mx:WindowedApplication everything behaves as expected: The label and the button are shown and the console shows the output of the two trace statements.

What am I missing?

I am using Flex 4.5.0 and use flex-mojos for the build.

Comment: Are you sure it compiled properly?  How'd you setup your project? How about your app.xml? which version of Air are you aiming for because there's been some changes to the underlying app config xml.

Comment: I am aiming towards AIR 2.6. It compiled and in both cases I can see the red background. To this stage my custom app.xml is not involved, but that could be a problem, as soon as I package an AIR app. However currently all I do is let my IDE, IntelliJ IDEA run the WindowedApplication class.

Comment: Not familiar with IntelliJ IDEA for Flex/AIR dev (I use FlashBuilder), but is your build a debug version? I don't think trace() works if it's not debug. BTW, I tried your code in FlashBuilder and it runs fine, so this is an issue with Flex-mojos configuration most likely.

Comment: That's strange.  My gut instincts tells me something is off with the compilation process.  I copy pasted your code exactly (after creating an air project in Flash Builder 4.5) and it compiled and ran without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it's your descriptor file that's off.  Here's the default one that Flash Builder created for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">

<!-- Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template.

    Specifies parameters for identifying, installing, and launching AIR applications.

    xmlns - The Adobe AIR namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6
            The last segment of the namespace specifies the version 
            of the AIR runtime required for this application to run.

    minimumPatchLevel - The minimum patch level of the AIR runtime required to run 
            the application. Optional.
-->

    <!-- A universally unique application identifier. Must be unique across all AIR applications.
    Using a reverse DNS-style name as the id is recommended. (Eg. com.example.ExampleApplication.) Required. -->
    <id>Airtest</id>

    <!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
    <filename>Airtest</filename>

    <!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
    May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <name>Airtest</name>

    <!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
    Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
    An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>

    <!-- A string value (such as "v1", "2.5", or "Alpha 1") that represents the version of the application, as it should be shown to users. Optional. -->
    <!-- <versionLabel></versionLabel> -->

    <!-- Description, displayed in the AIR application installer.
    May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <!-- <description></description> -->

    <!-- Copyright information. Optional -->
    <!-- <copyright></copyright> -->

    <!-- Publisher ID. Used if you're updating an application created prior to 1.5.3 -->
    <!-- <publisherID></publisherID> -->

    <!-- Settings for the application's initial window. Required. -->
    <initialWindow>
        <!-- The main SWF or HTML file of the application. Required. -->
        <!-- Note: In Flash Builder, the SWF reference is set automatically. -->
        <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>

        <!-- The title of the main window. Optional. -->
        <!-- <title></title> -->

        <!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
        <!-- <systemChrome></systemChrome> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is transparent. Only applicable when systemChrome is none. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <transparent></transparent> -->

        <!-- Whether the window is initially visible. Optional. Default false. -->
        <!-- <visible></visible> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can minimize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <minimizable></minimizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can maximize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <maximizable></maximizable> -->

        <!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
        <!-- <resizable></resizable> -->

        <!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <width></width> -->

        <!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
        <!-- <height></height> -->

        <!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <x></x> -->

        <!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
        <!-- <y></y> -->

        <!-- The window's minimum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "400 200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <minSize></minSize> -->

        <!-- The window's initial maximum size, specified as a width/height pair in pixels, such as "1600 1200". Optional. -->
        <!-- <maxSize></maxSize> -->

        <!-- The initial aspect ratio of the app when launched (either "portrait" or "landscape"). Optional. Mobile only. Default is the natural orientation of the device -->

        <!-- <aspectRatio></aspectRatio> -->

        <!-- Whether the app will begin auto-orienting on launch. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

        <!-- <autoOrients></autoOrients> -->

        <!-- Whether the app launches in full screen. Optional. Mobile only. Default false -->

        <!-- <fullScreen></fullScreen> -->

        <!-- The render mode for the app (either auto, cpu, or gpu). Optional. Mobile only. Default auto -->

        <!-- <renderMode></renderMode> -->

        <!-- Whether or not to pan when a soft keyboard is raised or lowered (either "pan" or "none").  Optional.  Defaults "pan." -->
        <!-- <softKeyboardBehavior></softKeyboardBehavior> -->
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </initialWindow>

    <!-- We recommend omitting the supportedProfiles element, -->
    <!-- which in turn permits your application to be deployed to all -->
    <!-- devices supported by AIR. If you wish to restrict deployment -->
    <!-- (i.e., to only mobile devices) then add this element and list -->
    <!-- only the profiles which your application does support. -->
    <!-- <supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop mobileDevice extendedMobileDevice</supportedProfiles> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
    <!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

    <!-- The subpath of the Programs menu to use. (Ignored on operating systems without a Programs menu.) Optional. -->
    <!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->

    <!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution,
    specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. -->
    <!-- <icon>
        <image16x16></image16x16>
        <image32x32></image32x32>
        <image36x36></image36x36>
        <image48x48></image48x48>
        <image72x72></image72x72>
        <image114x114></image114x114>
        <image128x128></image128x128>
    </icon> -->

    <!-- Whether the application handles the update when a user double-clicks an update version
    of the AIR file (true), or the default AIR application installer handles the update (false).
    Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <customUpdateUI></customUpdateUI> -->

    <!-- Whether the application can be launched when the user clicks a link in a web browser.
    Optional. Default false. -->
    <!-- <allowBrowserInvocation></allowBrowserInvocation> -->

    <!-- Listing of file types for which the application can register. Optional. -->
    <!-- <fileTypes> -->

        <!-- Defines one file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <fileType> -->

            <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
            <!-- <name></name> -->

            <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
            <!-- <extension></extension> -->

            <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
            <!-- <description></description> -->

            <!-- The MIME content type. -->
            <!-- <contentType></contentType> -->

            <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
            <!-- <icon>
                <image16x16></image16x16>
                <image32x32></image32x32>
                <image48x48></image48x48>
                <image128x128></image128x128>
            </icon> -->

        <!-- </fileType> -->
    <!-- </fileTypes> -->

    <!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
    <!-- <iPhone> -->
        <!-- A list of plist key/value pairs to be added to the application Info.plist -->
        <!-- <InfoAdditions>
            <![CDATA[
                <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
                <array>
                    <string>1</string>
                    <string>2</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <string>YES</string>
            ]]>
        </InfoAdditions> -->
        <!-- <requestedDisplayResolution></requestedDisplayResolution> -->
    <!-- </iPhone> -->

    <!-- Specify Android specific tags that get passed to AndroidManifest.xml file. -->
    <!--<android> 
        <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
                <uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="true"/>
                <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
                <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
                <application android:enabled="true">
                    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>
            </manifest>
        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions> 
    </android> -->
    <!-- End of the schema for adding the android specific tags in AndroidManifest.xml file -->

</application>
```

Comment: You were right! My run configuration was wrong. Obviously IDEA does not require a descriptor, when I've used mx:WindowedApplication, but required one for s:WindowsApplication.

So I've created a custom AIR run configuration and selected a proper descriptor here.

Comment: @J_A_X:I have the same problem as @Yaba, I'm using FB4.5, and if I use the default descriptor file (same as the one you posted ) I don't see anything, if I change `<visible>true</visible>` I get to see the window, but only the background. If I make it a mx WindowedApplication its all good...

Comment: @goliatone, I think you should start your own question and post the descriptor file and the code.

Comment: @J_A_X:I did not want to create a dup. I am using FB, thou, so meaby it would be best

Comment: @J_A_X:Ok, I just submitted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973891/flash-builder-4-5-swindowedapplication-does-not-initialize), perhaps you would like to check it out?