# Maven FlexMojos produces empty Air app. Final product has no window. Creates SWF but will not open it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, maven, air, flexmojos

### Problem

When I run my air application (compiled via flexmojos), it seems "empty"--there is no window at all.  It works perfectly when compiled from Flash Builder.

### Background

I am compiling an Adobe Air Application using Maven's flexmojos plugin on Mac OS X: Lion.  It successfully produces a SWF file and an AIR file.

- When I double-click the SWF file, it opens just fine
  (and crashes with an error you'd expect--since it's not running in the AIR environment)
- **When I double-click the AIR file, no window opens!**
  (I see my application name in the Mac menu bar but no application window and no errors)

When I look under `/Applications/MyApplication.app/Contents/Resources`
I see the following files:

```
META-INF            MyAppMainAir.swf
MyAppMainAir.css    mimetype
```

The swf file has the proper size and opens, as expected.

**POM snippet**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flexmojos.version}</version>
            <configuration>
            <flexBuilderCompatibility>true</flexBuilderCompatibility>
                <sourceFile>${application.name}.mxml</sourceFile>
                <finalName>${application.name}</finalName>
                <descriptorTemplate>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/${application.name}-app.xml</descriptorTemplate>
                <storepass>${keystore.password}</storepass>
                <includeStylesheets>
                    <stlyesheet>
                        <name>${application.name}.css</name>
                        <path>${application.name}.css</path>
                    </stlyesheet>
                </includeStylesheets>
                <licenses>
                    <flexbuilder3>${flex.license}</flexbuilder3>
                </licenses>
                <targetPlayer>10.2.0</targetPlayer>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign-air</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Question

Why is my SWF file being created properly but my AIR application won't open a window?  When I build/run the application from Flash Builder, it works perfectly.

Any input/advice is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried posting this question to the very active Flexmojos discussion group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/flex-mojos)?    You may get better traction there.

Comment: I just gave it a shot. Hopefully someone knows what's going on here because I'm completely stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

[After investigating this in the FlexMojos Google group](http://foo.com), it turns out, I needed to set the following option:

```
<swfVersion>11</swfVersion>
```

For some reason, this was defaulting to 10, which caused the problem.  Add this line, everything works perfectly!

### Alternate Fix

Alternatively, I was also able to fix the problem by loading the air-config.xml file:

```
<loadConfig>${flex.sdk}/frameworks/air-config.xml</loadConfig>
```

This file can also be found in the repository:

```
${path_to_m2_repo}/com/adobe/flex/framework/framework/${flex.sdk.version}/configs_zip/air-config.xml
```

where `flex.sdk.version=4.5.1.21328` , for example.

---

### Other Invisible Window Issue

Also for the intial window to appear, you may need to adjust the descriptor values, setting visible=true:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>Main.swf</content>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
</initialWindow>
```

The error I was having, combined with this set to false caused the window not appear, at all, which was confusing.  After setting visible=true, the window would at least show up but all spark contents were missing.  Once the error was fixed, I could set visible back to false.

Comment: To be complete, there's yet another "won't load" issue related to a corrupted mm.cfg file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973891/flash-builder-4-5-swindowedapplication-does-not-initialize